# How does the call function work with general registers

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-registers, calling-convention

Im trying to understand how the function call works in assembly
I have a line of code which im not sure I quite understand.

From what I understand is there's a call function waiting for a user input which seem to be an integer. The value is then added onto eax register. The value (8CAh) which is assumed to be "correct" value is then compared and if value is true the program ends, if not, we jump to another line of code.

Am I reading this correctly? And what exactly is the [ebp+var_10] ? Any help is appreciated :)

```
....
lea eax, [ebp+var_10]
mov [esp], eax
mov ecx, offset __imp__ZSt3cin; std::cin
call _ZNsirsERi ; std::istream::operator>>(int &)
sub esp, 4
mov eax, [ebp+var_10]
cmp eax, 8CAh
jnz loc_401645
```

Comment: 'ebp+var_10' is most likely the address of a member variable in a stack-allocated struct that holds the value entered by the user.

Comment: `[ebp+var_10]` is the local variable storing your input. `ebp` is presumably set up as frame pointer earlier. After your edit you can now see that the address of this variable is passed to `operator>>` so it writes the input there.

Comment: @Jester So after the value is stored in our local variable is it then compared to 8CAh?

Comment: @prl The program is a 32-bit executable on Windows. Not sure if this is what you mean.

Comment: @prl windows `thiscall` uses `ecx` for the `this` pointer in C++ code. See [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/thiscall)

Comment: I'm still uncertain of line 6 and 7 of the code. Can some kind soul explain this at a beginner level? :-)

Comment: Yes you got those correctly. `mov eax, [ebp+var_10]` just loads your variable from memory and `cmp eax, 8CAh` compares it to `8CAh` which is `2250` decimal.

Comment: Thank you @Jester that explains it all now :)